# Is it possible to "override" an interface through a proxy class?

Tags: java, oop, interface, proxy

I have a small set of methods from various classes that I'm exposing through a proxy-like convenience class. My issue is that one of those methods takes as an argument an instance of a class implementing an inner interface. I however, do not want to expose that interface through the original class, and would rather provide it through my proxy.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
Class C1 {
   public static void addSomeListener(SomeListener listener) {
       // Some code
   }

    public interface someListener {
        public void interfaceMethod();
    }
}

Class C2 {
    public interface someListener {
        public void interfaceMethod();
    }

    public static void doAddListener(SomeListener listener) {
        // The compiler, of course, complains here
        C1.addSomeListener(listener);
    }
 }
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow "override" that interface so that the interface from C2 can be exposed to the user/developer while still keeping the inner interface defined in C1 hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the job:

```
class C2 {
    public interface SomeOtherListener extends SomeListener {
        public void interfaceMethod();
    }

    public static void doAddListener(SomeOtherListener listener) {
        C1.addSomeListener(listener);
    }
 }
```